# drop_duplicates in a range

Tags: python, pandas, redundancy

I have a datraframe in python like that:

```
    st      se      st_min  st_max  se_min  se_max 
42  922444  923190  922434  922454  923180  923200
24  922445  923190  922435  922455  923180  923200
43  928718  929456  928708  928728  929446  929466
37  928718  929459  928708  928728  929449  929469
```

As we can see, I have a range in the first 2 columns and a variation of 10 positions of the initial range.

I know that function drop_duplicates can remove duplicate rows based on the exact match of values.

But, if I want to remove rows based on a range of values, for example, both indexes 42 and 24 are in the same range (if I considerer a range of 10) and indexes 43 and 37 are in the same case.

How I can do this?

Ps: I can't remove based only in one column (e.g. st or se), I need to remove redundancy based on both columns (st and se), using the range of columns min and max as filters...

Comment: You mean when given a row, you need to find all the rest row from which every element minus the corresponding element from the given row is in a range?

Comment: No, when a give a row, the st and se values should be compared with a range between st and se min ax max, like an if statement with range: if st in range (st_min,st_max), but inside a dataframe structure...

Comment: Sorry it's still not clear to me, do you mean only compare column `st` and `se` of 2 rows?

Comment: Do you only want to remove records whose range is completely included in another range, or do you also want to merge ranges? Lets say, if you have ranges 20-25, 22-24, 19-23, 24-28, would you expect those ranges to be replaced by just one range 19-28, or would you just expect that 22-24 is removed, because it is entirely included in 20-25?

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon Yeap.

Comment: @jottbe I want to remove rows that have numbers in a range at least 10 positions of difference from other rows, e.g. Remove index 24 because it has a position closely similar with index 42.

Comment: So you wouldn't want to make 20-25, 25-30 one range?

Comment: No, because those values are part of a BLAST analysis, and have other information linked with those positions, like score, identity... and I can't merge those values, because they are specific of 2 sequences.

I get my objective following the tip of @ Valdi_Bo using floordiv(10), in that manner, I create 2 new columns with the same values but without the last number (that make sense because I want to remove the rows with redundancy at least 10 positions). 

I really appreciate your support @jottbe, thanks a lot.

Best,

Comment: I think in that case you just need to adjust the `invalid_indexer` below, so it drops the joined values where the range overlaps, but not as much as you require. But if your ranges can be smaller than 10, you probably need those ranges separately, because they will not be present anymore in the aggregatd dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you want to combine all ranges. So that all ranges that overlap are reduced to one row. I think you need to do that recursively, because there could be multiple ranges, that form one big range, not just two. You could do it like this (just replace `df` by the variable you use to store your dataframe):

```
# create a dummy key column to produce a cartesian product
df['fake_key']=0
right_df= pd.DataFrame(df, copy=True)
right_df.rename({col: col + '_r' for col in right_df if col!='fake_key'}, axis='columns', inplace=True)

# this variable indicates that we need to perform the loop once more
change=True
# diff and new_diff are used to see, if the loop iteration changed something
# it's monotically increasing btw.
new_diff= (right_df['se_r'] - right_df['st_r']).sum()
while change:
    diff= new_diff
    joined_df= df.merge(right_df, on='fake_key')
    invalid_indexer= joined_df['se']<joined_df['st_r']    
    joined_df.drop(joined_df[invalid_indexer].index, axis='index', inplace=True)
    right_df= joined_df.groupby('st').aggregate({col: 'max' if '_min' not in col else 'min' for col in joined_df})
    # update the ..._min / ..._max fields in the combined range
    for col in ['st_min', 'se_min', 'st_max', 'se_max']:
        col_r= col + '_r'
        col1, col2= (col, col_r) if 'min' in col else (col_r, col)
        right_df[col_r]= right_df[col1].where(right_df[col1]<=right_df[col2], right_df[col2])
    right_df.drop(['se', 'st_r', 'st_min', 'se_min', 'st_max', 'se_max'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
    right_df.rename({'st': 'st_r'}, axis='columns', inplace=True)
    right_df['fake_key']=0
    # now check if we need to iterate once more
    new_diff= (right_df['se_r'] - right_df['st_r']).sum()
    change= diff <= new_diff

# now all ranges which overlap have the same value for se_r
# so we just need to aggregate on se_r to remove them
result= right_df.groupby('se_r').aggregate({col: 'min' if '_max' not in col else 'max' for col in right_df})
result.rename({col: col[:-2] if col.endswith('_r') else col for col in result}, axis='columns', inplace=True)
result.drop('fake_key', axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

If you execute this on your data, you get:

```
            st      se  st_min  st_max  se_min  se_max
se_r                                                  
923190  922444  923190  922434  922455  923180  923200
929459  928718  929459  922434  928728  923180  929469
```

Note, if your data set is larger than a few thousand records, you might need to change the join logic above which produces a cartesian product. So in the first iteration, you get a `joined_df` of the size n^2, where n is the number of records in your input dataframe. Then later in each iteration the `joined_df` will get smaller due to the aggregation.

I just ignored that, because I don't know, how large your dataset is. Avoiding this would make the code a bit more complex. But if you need it, you could just create an auxillary dataframe which allows you to "bin" the `se` values on both dataframes and use the binned value as the `fake_key`. It's not quite regular binning, you would have to create a dataframe that contains for each `fake_key` all values of the in the range (0...`fake_key`). So e.g. if you define your fake key to be `fake_key=se//1000`, your dataframe would contain

```
fake_key  fake_key_join
922       922
922       921
922       920
...       ...
922       0
```

If you replace the `merge` in the loop above by code, that merges such a dataframe on `fake_key` with `right_df` and the result on `fake_key_join` with `df` you can use the rest of the code and get the same result as above but without having to produce a full cartesian product.

Comment: thanks jottbe, I'm gonna test this, but I have other columns in my dataframe with another type of information, I'll check how your function will working with those others informations..

Answer (score 0):

Note that e.g. *st* values for keys *42* and *24* are **different**, so you can
not use just *st* values.

If e.g. your *range* can be defined as *st / 100* (rounded down to integer),
you can create a column with this value:

```
df['rng'] = df.st.floordiv(100)
```

Then use *drop_duplicates* with *subset* set to just this column and
drop *rng* column:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='rng').drop(columns=['rng'])
```

Or maybe *st* value for keys *24* should be **the same** as above (for key
*42*) and the same for *se* in the second pair of rows?
In this case you could use:

```
 df.drop_duplicates(subset=['st', 'se'])
```

without any auxiliary column.

Comment: this appear a good manner to work with that, I'm gonna test creating 2 columns with st and se with floordiv.